# Calculating user interaction for social network - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, formula

I'm working on a social network. I have to generate News Feed like posts for a user. We want posts from user friends first whom user is in high interaction. So, a simple formula that i thought of is this:

user priority = no. of interaction with this user / total no. of interaction with all users

this gives right answer but i want to know if it is efficient to just rely on this formula or should i consider other things as well.
example of this formula when user is:

user liked 5 posts of A and 3 posts pf B, so 5+3=8 interactions. now for each user, A is 5/8=0.625 and B is 3/8=0.375. So user is giving more priority to A, so show A posts first and than B's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other things to improve your algorithm might be:

- Dependency on time of last interaction. For ex, User A's 5 posts were liked a month ago but user B's posts were liked a week ago.
- Frequency of interaction. User A might have been interacting intermittently over a month but interaction with B is condensed over 2 days.
- Time spent on browsing the liked pages. This indicates quality or interest in the pages
- Kind of content liked by the user(through his or her own likes and posts) and kind of content generated by his friend circle. This would involve text processing
- Type of Relationship between the two. For ex, an uninteresting post from GF might have high priority then best mates' interesting one
- Total no of likes of the post - This might determine the overall interest in the content of that post.

You might also want to read this post here: [Understanding and building a social network algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010481/understanding-and-building-a-social-network-algorithm)

Comment: okay when generating posts, should i calculate this on every post generation, or i should calculate this and save this in database and calculate it on regular basis e.g after 24 hours. 2nd option seems efficient. what do u say ?

Comment: I think like this - Every user is a node whose importance changes with every post based on the calculations so you should calculate is in fixed intervals say 2hrs. so that the load on server doesn't peak out at once. And after each calculation, stash it in DB so at the time of post sending, you can refer to the aggregate calculations.